# I have configured 20 "Multi-configuration project" jobs in jenkins, now I want to trigger job one after another in a single job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-scriptler

I have configured 20 "Multi-configuration project" jobs in jenkins server(like, jobA, jobB, jobC, jobD, jobE, ....etc ), every job have seperate,these are the parent jobs. Now I created a single job(jobABC) with "Multi-configuration project". In "jobABC" I want to configure all 20 jobs to build one by one with condation(suppose jobA build SUCCESS then jobB build trigge, jobB build SUCCESS then jobC trigger and so on, otherwise if any job build failed then show the build is failed and don't trigger next job).

Actually, I have configured 20 individual jobs "Multi-configuration project" based job.

jobA
jobB
jobC
jobD
jobE
..... etc

Now, I want to configure one single job suppose ABCjob ("Multi-configuration project" based job).Inside ABCjob, I want to configure all 20 jobs and trigger automatically one after another but first one build success then trigger another job. if any stage failed then show fail and don't trigger another job.

Comment: You need to show more info on the problem, evidence of what research you have done and what you have tried so far before others can and will want to help out

Comment: Please explain why you can't do this with triggers. For instance when jobA finished you can implement a trigger to build jobB on success. You don't need jobABC for this. So why would you need jobABC?

Comment: actually, I want to trigger one single jobABC for deployment purpose so i am configuring like that. and it will show the sequence of the jobs.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday: [how to configure job in jekins if first project is build successful then trigger another project and so on with "Multi-configuration project" job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410466/how-to-configure-job-in-jekins-if-first-project-is-build-successful-then-trigger)